# What are the use cases of generic non-static methods?

Tags: java, generics

What is a valid use case for having a non-static method generic without having the class itself generic already?

Example:

```
public class A {
    <T> T someMethod(T param) {
        //use case?
    }
}
```

As shown above, the class is not parameterized, but the method is. When such structure can be used?

Please note that the above code is just an example. I am okay with all return types or parameters. I am just interested in a valid use case for a generic non-static method.

Comment: Are you sure it returns a `void` and accepts no parameters? If so, then it makes no sense to me either.

Comment: it would be hard to think of what such a method could do if it didn't have any parameters or a return type. normally you would make the method generic so that it could accept a generic type of some kind.

Comment: This question is theoretical, let's replace `void` by any other type and add any parameters.

Comment: A contrived use case: You want to merge two lists together, so two `List<T>`. But you do not want to make this utility `static` because maybe you want to log something or write some results to a database which are not in a static context.

Answer (score 2):

One use case is to infer compile-time type, but that would require your method to have actual return type, not just `void`.

Here is an example from [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java#L841)

```
public <T> T fromJson(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    if (json == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return (T) fromJson(new JsonTreeReader(json), typeOfT);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What are the use cases of generic non-static methods (if class itself
>   is not generic)?

One important use of this method signature is illustrated by the **type safe heterogenous container** pattern.  This pattern is useful in situations for which the container can represent many types (not just one single type, as is the case for `List<E>`).  In this pattern, the value's key is made generic instead of the container.

Here is the API for a type safe heterogenous container, taken from Essential Java, 2nd Ed. J. Bloch:

```
// Typesafe heterogeneous container pattern - API
public class Favorites {
   public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance);
   public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type);
}
```

This container maps keys, which are generic, to values whose type is represented by its corresponding key.  This pattern exploits the fact that the Java `Class` class was made generic in Java 5.  The generic `Class<T>` objects are used as *run time type tokens* which provide both compile-time and run-time type information for the corresponding values.

To store "favorite" `String` and `Integer` objects in the map, a client would write:

```
myFavs = new Favorites();
myFavs.putFavorite(String.class, "My Favorite String");
myFavs.putFavorite(Integer.class, Integer.valueOf(12345));
```

Note how the class literals are used as run-time type tokens which can then be used to restore the correct type to each value when it is retrieved from the map:

```
String myFavString = myFavs.getFavorite(String.class);
int myFavInt       = myFavs.getFavorite(Integer.class);
```

The type safe heterogenous container pattern, which is extendible to other kinds of data structures (eg. a row from a database, each column of which may have a different type), allows designers to implement data structures with an arbitrary number of unrelated types in a type safe way.

This is made possible by the fact that instance methods can be made generic.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class A {
    <T> T someMethod(T param) {
        //use case?
    }
}
```

Here if class it self is not generic, so you will be creating object of `A` as `A a = new A();`, but if there a requirement such that the `someMethod` in `A` should have generic parameter, in that case you will be using generics.

Example of such class can be, it I have `Calc` class which as `add` method.

```java
class Calc {

    <T> T add(<T extends Number> param1, <T extends Number> param2) {
       return param1 + param2;
    }

}
```

Here the above method can accept parameter which extends `Number` class only and it will return type that you have provided as parameter. Hence code will be more type safe.

```java
Calc c = new Calc();
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
calc.add(1, 2) // returns int 3
```

Comment: Note that this method could be made static. Also note that you can not use `+` on an `Object`, even if it extends `Number`. And finally, the bound requirement for `T` belongs to the declaration, not to the number itself. So `<T extends Number>` and then just `T param1, T param2`.

Comment: @Zabuza I was just explaining it with very basic example.

Comment: Sure. But maybe you want to take the time to improve the mentioned items. Then you will likely get more up-votes :)

Comment: I ll take that into consideration and will update the answer tomorrow. I ll update here so that u can have ur take on it. Thanks btw. :)